# Using PubSub Framework in iPhone Apps

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, frameworks, publish-subscribe

Is it posssible to use the Publication Subscription (PubSub) Cocoa framework in iPhone apps? I understand that the subscription features would not be available, but is it possible to use the feed-parsing features? (These would be very handy, since they handle multiple versions of RSS and malformed feeds.)

Comment: XMPP Framework for iPhone now supports PubSub.

Comment: The PubSub framework the OP is talking about has nothing to do with XMPP - so I don't see your point. Apple introduced a framework called PubSub that allows you to subscribe to RSS/Atom feeds and access the system wide RSS/Atom database on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PubSub is not currently available on iPhone.

Comment: It is now (2012 in the XMPPFramework for iphone).  Make sure that you grab the version after Nov 23, 2011 (in case anyone has old versions. There is an infinite loop bug that was fixed when you active a subscription.  Usually 10 times out of 10 when I have a bug, it's me. But in this case, it was the framework.)

Comment: The PubSub framework the OP is talking about has nothing to do with XMPP - so I don't see your point. Apple introduced a framework called PubSub that allows you to subscribe to RSS/Atom feeds and access the system wide RSS/Atom database on OS X.